# define array in source file and use it in other source file

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, c++11

i'm using visual C++ 2010.
the question confused me for a long time. i can define suan an array in *.cpp:

```
wstring pairs[][2] =
    {
        {L"\\ben\\b",               L"English"},
        {L"\\bfr\\b",               L"French"},
        {L"\\bit\\b",               L"Italian"},
        {L"\\bde\\b",               L"German"},
        {L"\\bes\\b",               L"Spanish"},
        {L"\\bpl\\b",               L"Polish"},
        {L"\\bru\\b",               L"Russian"},
        {L"\\bzh_cn\\b",            L"ChinesePRC"},
        {L"\\bzh_tw\\b",            L"ChineseTaiwan"},
        {L"\\bja\\b",               L"Japanese"},
        {L"\\bko\\b",               L"Korean"},
        {L"\\bpt\\b",               L"PortugueseStandard"},
        {L"\\btr\\b",               L"Turkish"},
        {L"\\bnl\\b",               L"Dutch"},
        {L"\\blt\\b",               L"Lithuanian"},
        {L"\\blv\\b",               L"Latvian"},
        {L"\\bet\\b",               L"Estonian"}
    };
```

and declare the array in *.h like this:

```
extern wstring pairs[][2];
```

now i can use the array in other *.cpp, but i can't get the size of `pairs` use the code:

```
size_t cnt = _countof(pairs);
```

i got the error message:

```
1>e:\work\vc++\justtest\console\console.cpp(45): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'char (*__countof_helper(_CountofType (&)[_SizeOfArray]))[_SizeOfArray]'
1>          With the following template arguments:
1>          'std::wstring [2]'
```

i'm confused whether it is possible to use array like this?
anybody can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the length of an `extern` array, you must explicitly declare the length of the array in the header file. Otherwise, the compiler simply does not have access to that information; it's buried in the defining object file, which the compiler will not read.

There are two other ways you might be able to do what you want:

1. You might create another variable for the length of the array. Then do an `extern` for that, too, and you'll be able to access the length in the other file.

   **Downside:** The length still will not be *statically* known. However, if you've got link-time optimization (unlikely) and aren't using the value for any fancy metaprogramming, that might not be a problem.
2. You could add a sentinel value at the end marking the end of the array.

   **Downside:** The length will not be statically known with this approach, either. Furthermore, every time you want the length of the array, it's an O(n) operation. This may not be a problem if you only ever iterate through the array.

Comment: LTO is enabled by default in VC++.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array with an `extern`, but you either (1) need to make the declaration of the size explicit, or (2) put a terminator entry, similar to null terminator in a string, to count the number of entries at runtime.

Solution 1:

```
extern wstring pairs[17][2];
```

With this change, `sizeof(pairs)` would be defined correctly.

Solution 2:

```
wstring pairs[][2] =
{
    {L"\\ben\\b",               L"English"},
    {L"\\bfr\\b",               L"French"},
    ...
    {L"\\blv\\b",               L"Latvian"},
    {L"\\bet\\b",               L"Estonian"}, {0, 0}
};
```

Now you can run a quick loop through `pairs` to get to `*pairs[i] == 0`, which would indicate the last entry.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `_countof` is a template function which needs to know the array size at compile time.  And at compile time, only your `extern` declaration is visible, and it doesn't mention the array size.

One possible work around is to add another variable to hold the size. Header:

```
extern wstring pairs[][2];
extern const size_t pairs_size;
```

Source:

```
wstring pairs[][2] = { /*...*/ };
const size_t pairs_size = _countof(pairs);
```

Or, as others have suggested, use a sentry to determine the array size at run-time.

Or, if the usage permits, switch to a `std::vector` or other container.  (This might mess with the order of static initializers.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `{ NULL, NULL }` to the end of your array. Then use a loop somewhat like this:

```
extern wstring pairs[][2];
...
int do_stuff()
{
    for(int i = 0; pairs[i][0] != NULL; i++)
    {
      ... do things with pairs as you like ... 
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Close but no medal. Here's something that should work with most modern compilers. In the source file where the array is declared, do something like:

```
const unsigned int amrd_count=sizeof( amrd ) /sizeof( amrd[0] );
```

In your headers, insert something like:

```
extern T amrd[];
extern const unsigned int amrd_count;
```

For me, this works with XCode (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)) and gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)

Comment: I love that I posted an actual solution that works and is easy, but got zero votes. The more cumbersome solutions all got voted up though.